# How to fetch Build information in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I've build a sample project in Jenkins by cloning from the Github repo. Can I get all the Jenkins and Git build details (such as the last commit ID, Origin details, Jenkins build number, Build URL, workspace location of Jenkins, Last commit author name) in a HTML page (It should be created after jenkins build) after triggering a build in Jenkins?

Comment: I don't think so there is any such plugin but these info are easily available via some variables in Jenkins may be you can apply some logic of your own to redirect this variables to a html file

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins and Git provide global variables which can be directly accessed in jobs irrespective of pre build or post build actions.
You can check global variable list with below url.

```
http://your-jenkins-url-here/env-vars.html
```

To access user defined variables, you can use below regex pattern:

`${ENV,var="MY_VARIABLE_NAME"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the variables of the Jenkins pipeline by the below:-

```
script {
      // Prints all the variables
      sh "printenv"
}
```

After this you can store all the variables inside a file and publish that file using the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/publishing-html-reports-pipeline) to get the result in a HTML page. You can make changes in the below code:-

`publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: 'fileDirectory', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'HTML Report', reportTitles: 'titleName']`)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo(env.getEnvironment().collect({environmentVariable ->  "${environmentVariable.key} = ${environmentVariable.value}"}).join("\n"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78234218/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow Thanks!